# A4j components are not working in the backing bean

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf, jsf-2.2

I have an application which uses Jsf 1.2, Richfaces 3.3.3, and many more plugins. I wanted to upgrade this app to higher versions of Jsf 2.2.1 and Richfaces 4.3.3. What I did is I created an app from scratch and set all the dependencies and settings for the newer versions of the plugins. I want to upgrade the app page by page since Richfaces 4.x differes alot from 3.x. In the old app all the A4j components like commandLink and commandButton are working properly in the backing bean; however, those components are not resolved for the new versions. The followings cannot be resolved:

```
import org.ajax4jsf.component.html.HtmlAjaxCommandButton;
import org.ajax4jsf.component.html.HtmlAjaxCommandLink;
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages have been changed, you probably want

```
org.richfaces.component.UICommandButton
org.richfaces.component.UICommandLink
```

here's the [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/javadoc/richfaces-components-ui/index.html)

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. In my old app, I have used "rich:comboBox" component which was in the package "org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlComboBox" but now I couldn't find any component as comboBox. Did this component change to a different name?

Comment: It's now `rich:suggestionBox`, take a look at these [migration](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration)(1) [guides](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces33-4xMigrationGuideUnleashed)(2) for further info.